# Asp.net MVC3 Razor view engine, escape several lines of text using "Multiline @:"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I was working on a project and came to a point where I need to do something like this:

```
foreach(var item in Model)
{
@:<div class="my-class"> this is some content </div>
@:<div class="my-other-class">this is some more content </div>
}
```

But, of course, it would be stupid to do it like this. So my question is:

-Is there a notation to escape several lines of html code like the example given above?

E.g.

```
@: <div>
   <div>
   <div> :@
```

Your help is much appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: er.. there's no razor syntax in your code sample, it's pure HTML so no need for @: at all ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use @ only to scope access or delimit c-sharp/vb code in the view. Pure HTML can live alone as pure HTML, for exemple:

Delimits a valiable assignment:

```
@{ 
   int x = 123; 
   string y = "because.";
}
```

Use the variable x into the code

```
<div>@x</div>
```

Use the variable y into the code

```
<div>@y</div>
```

Use x and y at the same time

```
@{ 
   <div>@x</div>
   <div>@y</div>
}
```

For:

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
  <div class="my-class"> @item.SomeProperty </div>
  <div class="my-other-class">this is some more content </div>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@{  <text><div></div></text> }
```

use `<text></text>`

Answer (score 1):

Use `@{  }`

```
@{ 
   <div>
   <div>
   <div> 
}
```

Although you're not using the Razor engine for anything useful in this context, you could simply omit them.

As an alternative you could simply add an `@` before the `foreach`:

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
   <div class="my-class"> @item.Property </div>
   <div class="my-other-class">this is some more content </div>

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah yes, the problem was my structure. It's true that html code persists on its own.

The problem was I had a block in which I would insert a different  starting tag according to a condition

`if(cond) { insert <div> } else {insert other div}`

And so I guess the CLR couldn't see the closing `}` .

Fixed it by putting the whole `<div></div>` structure inside the condition blocks.

Thanks for your replies tho, cheers!